# Redux extension not showing store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm learning redux and for the purposes of debugging I installed their debugging extenion in Chrome. Aside form my code not working, why isn't the extension showing the store data despite the latter being initialized by `const store = createStore(counter);`?

[image: Redux extension not displaying data]

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import App from "./App";

const store = createStore(counter);

function counter(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return state + 1;
    case "DECREMENT":
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{store.getState()}</p>
      <button onClick={() => store.dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT" })}>
        Increment
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-p8vm7h?file=src/index.js

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [the store needs to be configured so that the extension can listen for changes and read its state](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#1-with-redux).  Your code just creates a plain store by itself, without any of the DevTools connection setup.

You should switch to using [the `configureStore` API](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore) from [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), which is our recommended approach for writing Redux logic.  `configureStore` automatically sets up the store to work with the DevTools Extension, and adds additional checks that prevent common mistakes like accidental mutations.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [GitHub](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension) page from the creator itself. It explains very well how to connect Store and the extension. If you need more information, do let me know in comments